# How to rename Liferay's default cookies?

Tags: cookies, liferay, rename

I have JSP project which uses Liferay framework. There are default Liferay cookies named `COOKIE_SUPPORT` and `GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID` in Liferay. I dont want hackers to view any of my technology information by any means. How can I rename these cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to protect the framework you're using, you won't have to worry about the names of the cookies. Worry about server identification, elements of the DOM, structure and mechanics of URLs, secure&hardened setup of your server, common translations, default content, standard error messages, etc.

In other words: If you don't want to give away, which standard framework you're using (and this is not limited to Liferay) you'll have to roll your own. Good luck with getting this as powerful and as well tested as any standard framework.

Rather worry about keeping your systems updated all the time and protect from well known vulnerabilities in older systems. For hardening Liferay specifically, you might want to start with my blog series on [securing Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/securing-liferay-chapter-1-introduction-basics-and-operating-system-level) (linking chapter 1 which refers to the other chapters)

Promoting a comment into this answer: One way to find out how to change them is to search for their names in the source code and identify the kind of plugin you need to provide different values - most likely this will be an ext-plugin. After all, Liferay's source is available. I don't see anything short of this.

Comment: I have a securely configured server I believe and I would like to concentrate specifically on framework security. Thanks for the link. Will look into it. Meanwhile It would be useful if you could share the method to disable the information leakage through cookie name.

Comment: It's not that I'm keeping the information back - My answer is about the reason why *I* find it irrelevant. The cookie names you give don't really give away the platform while so many other things that you find on the page do. One way to find out how to change them is to search for their names in the source code and identify the kind of plugin you need to provide different values - most likely this will be an ext-plugin. After all, Liferay's source is available.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have edited `server` information to `technology` information in my question. I don't really want to expose anything, not even the Liferay name. Its a matter of security according to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fingerprint_Web_Application_Framework_%28OTG-INFO-008%29).